# Volume of Cylindrical Shells

Tags: calculus

I am currently trying to solve a homework problem that asks: "Use the Shell Method to calculate the volume of rotation, $V$, about the x-axis for the region underneath the graph of $y=(x-4)^{1/3}-2$ where $12\le x\le 31$ ." I have already drawn the image and have found the radius of each shell to equal y, but I am unsure as to what the height of each shell would be. I am also not positive if i would integrate the volume from 12 to 31 or from 0 to 1. It would be greatly appreciated if someone could help me solve this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The function is $x=4+(y+2)^3$ and hence the volume is 
$$V=2\pi\int_0^1 yf(y)dy=2\pi\int_0^1 y[4+(y+2)^3]dy$$